Infinity or NaH toInt error when calling customWidget from multiple classes
I have a customwidget that displays a map and a marker. If works fine when I call it from the first page, but when I call the custom widget from the second class it gives me a unsopported operation: infinity or NaN toInt error.
customWidget.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart';

class CustomMap extends StatelessWidget {
  String? choice;

  CustomMap({required this.choice});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FlutterMap(
        
        options: const MapOptions (
        initialCenter: LatLng(38.8977, -77.0365),
        initialZoom: 19,
        interactionOptions:
          InteractionOptions(flags: ~InteractiveFlag.doubleTapZoom)
      ), 
      children: [
        openStreetMapTileLayer,

       CircleLayer(
            circles: [
              CircleMarker(
                point: const LatLng(38.8977, -77.0365),
                radius: 30,
                borderColor: Colors.blue,
                borderStrokeWidth: 5,
                useRadiusInMeter: true,
                color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 206, 192, 192).withOpacity(0.5))
            ]
            
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}


TileLayer get openStreetMapTileLayer => TileLayer (
      urlTemplate: 'https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
      userAgentPackageName: 'dev.fleaflet.flutter_map.example',
);

I call it from main.dart here and works just fine
 body: Stack(
         
          children: [
            FlutterMap(
            options: const MapOptions(),
            
            children: [
              CustomMap(
                choice: "two",
              ),
              //content(),

error starts when I call it from SecondPage where I route to from main.dart using MaterialPageRoute
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_flutter_app/customWidget.dart';

class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
    // This is a String for the sake of an example.
  // You can use any type you want.

  const SecondPage({super.key});

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {

  final String data = "123";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,

        title: const Text('Map 2'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[

            CustomMap(
              choice: "one",
            ),

      
            Text(
              data,
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}

I added a ? to the string variable because it would complain about nullable errors without it. and also I made it required to pass a string. But somewhere its still complaining about NaN.
Any help would be appreciated
